# Create a variable based on the value of a string

Tags: python, dry

I would like to initiate a class based on a list of name of variable.

To clarify, here is my non-DRY code :

```
    def __init__(self, page):
        self.page_id = page.page_id
        self.page_access_token = page.page_access_token
        self.page_fans_country = _get(obj=self._request(endpoint='page_fans_country', period=''))
        self.page_fans_gender_age = _get(obj=self._request(endpoint='page_fans_gender_age', period=''),)
        self.page_impressions = _get(obj=self._request(endpoint='page_impressions', period=''))
        self.page_impressions_unique = _get(obj=self._request(endpoint='page_impressions_unique', period=''))
        self.page_impressions_by_country_unique = _get(obj=self._request(endpoint='page_impressions_by_country_unique', period=''))
        self.page_impressions_by_age_gender_unique = _get(obj=self._request(endpoint='page_impressions_by_age_gender_unique', period=''))
        self.page_engaged_users = _get(obj=self._request(endpoint='page_engaged_users', period=''))
        self.page_consumptions = _get(obj=self._request(endpoint='page_consumptions', period=''))
        self.page_consumptions_unique = _get(obj=self._request(endpoint='page_consumptions_unique', period=''))
```

It is not DRY - in case I want to change the name of the endpoint, i need to make the change twice.

Is there any way to perform this :

```
def __init__(self, page):
    self.page_id = page.page_id
    self.page_access_token = page.page_access_token

    list = ['page_fans_country','page_fans_gender_age',(...)]

    for element in list:
        self.{ var with the name of element } = _get(obj=self._request(endpoint=element, period=''))
```

Comment: Have you tried hasattr/getattr ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like what you'll generally use [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) for. And then, you may use a function to clean up the verbose call to `_get`:

```
class Dry(object):
    def __init__(self, page):
        ...
        for item in lst:
            setattr(self, item, self.alloc(item))

    def alloc(self, endpoint, period=''):
        return _get(obj=self._request(endpoint=endpoint, period=period))
```